# Am I going to run out of stack memory eventually after this code?

Tags: python-2.7, timer

```
import threading

def func():
    print "hello"
    threading.Timer(5.0,func).start()
func()
```

Technically I just want to use it to create a timer which repeats its task after 5 seconds indefinitely.

Comment: Can you clarify more your question? Technically your code create a timer which repeats its task after 5 seconds indefinitely. In other hand with your  code you don't have problems of stack overflow because in every called of your method you print hello and create a thread that execute your code in 5 seconds again. In my computer with a dual core processes of 1.8 Ghz and Ram 4Gb this process spend cpu: 0.6% an mem: 0.2

Comment: Actually the thing is I'm running an IRC bot and I'm pretty new to how threads work in python (I'm used to java). So, instead of using time.sleep() (which I think might make my bot timeout) I wanted to use threads with some kind of timer.

Comment: Ok but this from my point of view is more general, maybe you need some books, maybe you need read again the politics of this site, you need put here something like a problem of your code or something specific and in the body of your question, maybe you can fiend the answer in others question, maybe you can post many question related  with this topic, I vote-down because I think that you need improve your question.

Comment: That downvote was totally not required, because my question was pretty straightforward and was answered. I only needed to know whether I would eventually run out of stack memory or not and I got my answer. Why should I bother to give extra details where I feel they aren't required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand why you need to import threading. Time should do it:

```
import time

def hello():
    print "Hello"

while 1:
    hello()
    time.sleep(5)
```

And to answer your question, no, I dont believe memory will be an issue.